# How does Webpack find the package in node_modules

Tags: webpack

When i am using a UI library in my project, I found the usage of this component can be like:

```
import { badge } from 'lib-name'
```

and i checked the log that how does Webpack search this module. And i found Webpack just "modified" the path to look for:

```
/node_modules/lib-name/lib/badge.vue
```

So it is a feature provided by webpack?

Answer (score 0):

No, webpack runs on node process and it uses [node module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-nodejs-resolves-modules).

Typescript mimic node module resolution algorithm. (It has classic or node options for resolution in tsconfig resolution option)

The algorithm doesn’t “sits” in webpack.
Information regarding the specific algorithm is in the link.

After it finds node modules, it looks in the main property of the package.json for the entry file to run, in your example - badge.vue